# Do Linux system administration skills transfer across distributions?

Tags: linux

If I learned Linux administration on a specific distribution, will those skills be applicable to any other distribution as well?

Do I have to re-learn everything from scratch each time I touch another distribution? If not, what can I expect to be the same and what can I expect to change?

Comment: "I have a very important begginer question?" is a *very* poor title for your question. It doesn't give anyone any idea whatsoever what you're asking.

Comment: I did a pretty extensive edit on your original question to try and make it a bit more specific and answereable.

Comment: With @terdon's edit, the question is pretty clear and relevant I'd say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some things change while others do not. One of the main differences between the different Linux distributions is their software package management. For example, the Debian world (Debian, Ubuntu, Mint etc) use `dpkg` and `apt-get` while the Red Hat world (RHEL, CentOS, openSuSe etc) use `rpm` and others can use yet other tools. The basic ideas will be the same but the specific tools you use to administer and install software will change.

Things like user administration, security, file management etc will be the same across distributions with only minor, aesthetic changes or no changes at all.

So yes, some things will change and others will not. A competent Linux systems administrator will be able to learn a new system very very quickly however since most of the changes are about the higher level tools used to administer the installed packages.

Comment: More significant than the package manager is probably differences in [init system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init).  There are currently at least three very different ones in widespread use on linux (systemd, upstart, and SysV).

Comment: @goldilocks ah, indeed, good point. I thought upstart was dead though. Either way, I am not up do date enough on the init systems (I've been hoping things will eventually settle down again) so I can't really do them justice in an answer.

Comment: @terdon not while 14.04 draws breath. :P At any rate, it will still be worth learning for a couple of years.

Comment: Since debian is moving to systemd too, there will one day be one ring to bind them all again!  Mostly. But not yet.